# Redirect not authorized pages to specific page in Cakephp 3

Tags: authentication, cakephp-3.0

I want to redirect not authorized pages to a specific page.

In my controller, I have to allowe functions `$this->Auth->allow(['registerCompany', 'login']);` which I can access irrespective of whether I am logged in or not.

I want that, when each time when a not-logged user tries to access a function that is not allowed, the user should be redirected to a specific page.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You want to set `unauthorizedRedirect` in the [configuration options](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuration-options) of the `AuthComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in auth component there is a property to set login redirect. Please check loginRedirect option.

public $components = array('Auth' => array('loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'login'),'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?');}